# Use variable in SQL query c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-insert

How can I use variable in SQL query?

For example:

```
String n = "jack";
Int a = 23;
Conn.open();
SQLcommand CMD (insert into table (name,age) values (n, a);
CMD.executenonquery();
```

Is this code ok? Or I should use:

```
CMD.parameters.adwithvalue(@a,a)
```

Comment: Aside from the syntax errors in your example, yes you could, but you never have to. Always use parameters to pass values that come from user input to your queries

Comment: Unless your question is. Can I write a query like this _SQLcommand CMD = "insert into sometable (name,age) values (n, a)";_ and expect that _n_ and _a_ are replaced by their values , so the query text becomes _"insert into sometable (name,age) values ('Jack', 23)";_ . In this case no, it doesn't work in that way.

Comment: Never use AddWithValue: [1](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [2](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), [3](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TABLE (name,age) values (@name,@age)");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", n);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", n);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You can also use it this way.

Comment: Never use AddWithValue: [1](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [2](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), [3](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 1):

```
using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();

var query = "INSERT INTO YourTableName (name, age) VALUES (@Name, @Age)";

using var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);    
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", n);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", a);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```